# MatchesMask for Widestring?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need MatchesMask (or similar) function for WideStrings, not only string. I can't find any such function in TNT Unicode Controls. Where can i find it for Delphi7, maybe in some library?

Answer (score 1):

Found --

```
function PathMatchSpecW(const pszFileParam, pszSpec: PWideChar): Bool; stdcall; external 'shlwapi';
```

> This Windows API Call is much faster than
>   MatchesMask and can handle WideStrings.